# Unable to send request from client to server using their certificates and making SOAP API calls using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate, soap-client, client-certificates

I am trying to send a request and trying to establish connection between client and server. I converted the certificates into .pem files and saved the private key from .pem file into another file which starts with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  ... -----END PRIVATE KEY----- and saved it as .key file. Then I added that private key of certificate file into server certificate .pem file. I thought by doing this connection between client and server will establish. I get 200 but I don't get any response.. please help

```
    import json
    import requests
    clientCrt = "path to client certificate\\ce.crt"
    certificate_secret = "path to client's private key\\pkey.key"
    url = "api_end_point_url"
    certServer = "path to server certificate\\serv.pem"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
    payload = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="...">
   <soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<ns:OrigXARequest>
<Request>
.....
</Request>
</ns:OrigXARequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

    response = requests.get(url, data=payload, verify = certServer,
                        headers=headers, cert=(clientCrt,certificate_secret))
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
    print(response.text)`
```

Output

```
200
    b'<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><soap:Fault xsi:type="soap:Fault"><faultcode>RTL-API-1002</faultcode><faultstring>Error occurred while invoking the .. Web Service.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. The issue was not with client certificate or server certificate. I was not getting any response because the request was going to the wrong SOAP Address. Once I fixed the address, my code worked. Thank you all.